# Running delayed job using bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, delayed-job

In general, I will start the delayed_job using cmd:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

Now I wrote a simple upstart script to automatically start the delayed job after reboot.

I found that if I wrote the cmd above in the script, it will fail.

```
# this is the execution in the upstart conf
exec RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

After some google and test, I found this would work in my script:

```
 exec bundle exec /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

This resulted in my question, I guess `/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production` is to pass the environment variable into the bin/delay_job script, how about bundle exec here?

Without having bundle exec in the script, it will throw error regarding to

`require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)`.

I realized that using bundle exec helps run rails under some context of the environment, but why is it necessary in the script?
Or is `bundle exec`  necessary when I want to execute cmd like `bin/delayed_job` or `rake` in the script?

Thanks.

**updated**

I copied the upstart script to another node and executed it the same way.
However, it throws the incompatible library version error...
I run

```
 bundle exec /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

directly on terminal and it worked as expected, but failed when putting the command above in a script.

Could someone tell me why the result differed when executing the same command but in different place?